# How to zoom in/out an drawable imageView on some condition satisfied

Tags: android, zooming, imageview

helo, 
   I am new to android and trying to implement some action.  I have one drawable image set in imageview.  I would like to zoomIn it at some specific Coordinates on ImageView When some condition (specified) is satisfied. And on satisfying some other condition I like to zoom Out that image.  how can I achieve this functionality.  Can any one help me...please.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an empty mutable bitmap object as described below and you can do alterations to this bitmap and then  setImageBitmap using imageview.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(1.5f, 1.0f,0, 0);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
```

Comment: Does it loose quality when zoom if drawable from pure SVG?